# Packaging Images with SQL Server Script

Tags: sql-server

i have a sql server db which needs to be deployed with an asp.net application. In a particular master table data is populated via a batch when installing the app. There are some images which must be saved in the db during installation. How do I package these images and how do I supply the path to these images ?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, they will end up as binary data. So you can script them out as a hexadecimal string, like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable(ImageColumn)
VALUES (0x104321943324798543...)
```

That's the simplest way. There are plenty of tools that can do the scripting for you, the IDE that I wrote (which you can find [here](http://www.atlantis-interactive.co.uk/products/sqleverywhere/default.aspx)) included.